# Update with proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

Good day,

I want to update table so that I flag which have distance between two columns. I was thinking of making this with **proc sql**. I can do this by few different datasets, but single command would be much more elegant.

However, the code below gives me the following error:

```
proc sql noprint; 
    update devStuff set flag =1  where portal in  
    (select distinct(portal) from devStuff 
    group by country, portal
    having  abs(max(last_proc) - max(pvm) ) >= 3) 
; quit;
```

> ERROR: You cannot reopen WORK.DEVSTUFF.DATA for update access with member-level control because
>   WORK.DEVSTUFF.DATA is in use by you in resource environment SQL.
>   ERROR: PROC SQL could not undo this statement if an ERROR were to happen as it could not obtain
>          exclusive access to the data set. This statement will not execute as the SQL option
>          UNDO_POLICY=REQUIRED is in effect.

Apparently I can not sub-query the dataset I want to update. (Yeah, this should be normal in 'real sql'.)

**Is this is 'just the way it is' or is there clever work around?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make changes to a table you are querying, try changing your proc sql statement:

```
proc sql undo_policy=none noprint;
```

This is the option that the error message in the log is hinting at.